# c# socket server and client

Tags: c#, sockets

Have anyone able to use visual studio socket server and client to work successfully over WAN network and not LAN??  I got it to work on LAN but not over the WAN.

Comment: What problem are you having over WAN?  "It doesn't work" is not a sufficient description for any problem.

Comment: Are you using a router on the server side when testing your application over the WAN? If so, did you think about forwarding the port for the server so the client can connect?

Answer (score 1):

By far the most common cause of problems when you go from LAN to WAN is firewall setup. If the server process is behind a NAT firewall, then you will need to connect to the [public IP address](http://whatismyipaddress.com/) assigned to you by your ISP, but it won't work until you set up a pinhole in the firewall's configuration that directs incoming connections to the appropriate internal IP/port.